# help me find a minimal-friction logging solution for asp.net apps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, logging

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that I have 30 asp.net web applications (and sites, blerg) that need to have a logging framework. My current solution is to use Enterprise Library Logging. Getting this going on a site involves the following steps:

1. add references to two assemblies (EL Logging and Common)
2. add code to Global.asax.cs for generic unhandled error trapping
3. copy in enterpriseLibrary.config, copied from another app that already has logging
4. copy in FileConfigurationSource.cs (which allows you to override the requirement for a hardcoded path to the enterpriseLibrary.config)
5. change namespace in FileConfigurationSource.cs to the new project
6. copy web.config sections from another project that are specific to EL (2 sections)
7. change namespaces in web.config for EL in new project
8. test and make sure it's working (usually by taking the database offline)

All of that is the friction that I'm talking about. That's a lot of violations of DRY if you ask me, especially in all the enterpriseLibrary.config settings. Ideally, adding logging would be a two step process -- that will help me get it adopted across the team.

I wonder if there's a logging solution for .net that **doesn't have all these repetitions**? All of them that I can find (log4net, nlog, EL Logging) seem to use this "every app has it's own configuration with plenty of repetition" pattern. Perhaps I'm missing something.

In practice, every one of our apps will have a logging solution that's 99% identical to the other ones. They will differ in where they store their logs and what the app is called. Is there a way to use one of the big three logging solutions that let's you set the logging behavior at a machine level or in a more centralized place? I realize that there are downsides to having a centralized logging configuration.

Also important: must be able to change logging level **on the fly** (no storing logging config in web.config, causing an app restart) and the logging must be configurable as part of a deployment (don't want an email to be sent on critical errors on the beta server). These two make using web.config transforms difficult since running a transform on a .config as part of your build that isn't a web.config is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a perfect solution for a problem similar to yours.

I have ten console applications, two ASP .NET websites and three SharePoint webparts **logging to a single directory, the logs being separated by date, application name**, etc. The solution is very configurable and flexible and **allows configuration changes on the fly**.

All this glory was brought to life by [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), which allows for a single configuration file being [included](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file#Include_files) from application-specific configuration files.

To be more specific, in our case each project contains **individual** NLog config that reads as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <include file="PATH TO THE SHARED CONFIG" /> <!-- change this line -->
</nlog>
```

For *web* applications, individual NLog configuration [can be read from](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file#Configuration_file_locations):

- standard web application file `web.config`
- `web.nlog` located in the same directory as `web.config`
- `NLog.config` in application’s directory
- `NLog.dll.nlog` in a directory where `NLog.dll` is located

**Shared** configuration file can be placed **anywhere ASP .NET process can read**, and also has `autoReload="true"` which allows on-the-fly modifications. In our case, it defines different [targets](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Targets) for log messages, such as email, log files in different directories, et cetera.

Comment: The inclusion of other log files is a nice feature. I'll look into it and see if I can implement some sort of "machine level" logging config.

Comment: @jcollum: it is nice indeed, you can also use variables in file names which adds flexibility.

Comment: @jcollum: I updated the answer with some clarification. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks, now I need to get around the adding code to global.asax.cs issue. I think ELMAH might be the answer, but it has the same config issue.

Comment: @jcollum: Sorry, what kind of code are you talking about? NLog doesn't require adding any code to `global.asax.cs` AFAIK.

Comment: We're using code in global.asax.cs to catch unhandled errors in Application_Error.

Comment: I thought the main problem was having to drag around some files and messing with EL configuration (which is solved by using NLog). Is adding logging code to `Application_Error` a problem as well?

Comment: Well ideally I'd not have to do it -- it's the exact same code in every app so big violation of DRY

Comment: I wouldn't say so. DRY means you shouldn't throw *meaningful* code around the system. Because when you change logic in one place, you may forget about the other. However sometimes you need to repeat yourself in boilerplate code—and although it's not pleasant, it doesn't mean you *repeat yourself*. Rather, you repeat some boring stuff that you didn't even *mean* to write, but you have to. Anyway, nothing stops you from writing a library on top of NLog that encapsulates logger, as well as provides an `Application_Error` callback you can register in one line. Can you really go simpler than that?